# Why ngx-bootstrap tooptip is under some layers

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

[image]
[image]

Our project used `Angular 5` and `ngx-bootstrap`.
When I used `tooltip` of `ngx-bootstrap`, found that the `tooltip` always is under some layers, event it has the highest z-index, it is too strange....
Is there someone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you already try to use "Append to Body"?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
        container="body">
  Tooltip appended to body
</button>
```

Comment: you are right, i forgot add container, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi claboran, if i append the tooltip to body, in mobile mode, if the tooltip is too width, will expand the screen, that means user can drag the screen in  x direction, how to prevent this?  i have tried to apply max-width: 100vw, overflow-x: hidden to html and body elements, but the screen can also be draggable

Comment: @Abby: Two things are coming to my mind: 1.) Did you use /deep/ to set the CSS from Host? 2.) Try to get full control by using a template reference for the tooltip.